# Standard script database variables (Oracle vs Sql Server Terminology)

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, scripting, terminology

What are the differences/equivalences between Microsoft Sql and Oracle connection parameters, and **are there some common names they map to**?  Things like "database", "instance", "username", "tablespace".

From [Help me put Oracle terminology into SQL Server terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087076/help-me-put-oracle-terminology-into-sql-server-terminology/1087934#1087934) we get:

```
| Oracle       | Sql Server    | Universal|
===========================================
| Tablespace   |               |          |
| Database     |               |          |
| Listener     |               |          |
| Instance     | Instance      |          |
| Schema       | Database      |          |
| Service Name | Database Name |          |
| SID          | Database Name |          |
-------------------------------------------
```

But I'm looking for a universal naming scheme that I can use in application upgrade scripts (as we need to use connection substitution parameters for both databases...).

Is [Java's DatabaseMetaData](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) a reasonable object to study?

Is the above table even appropriate? Using connection parameters, the oracle username is the schema name (yes?), and so I'd have a `db.user` property, and never 'db.schema`?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087076/help-me-put-oracle-terminology-into-sql-server-terminology

Comment: Oracle Database != SQL Server instance. An Oracle "Database" refers only to the actual data files, not the running program.

Comment: "Oracle Database != SQL Server instance".  Ahhh that's right.  Oracle has a database with files, and instances run on top of those (usually 1-1).  Sql Server has an Instance, with databases (and files) running inside.

I just got confused about the layering...

Comment: Actually, this is a different question - I'm wanting to fill the third column above... am I able to remove my "close" vote now?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is reasonably ok:

```
| Oracle        | Sql Server    | Universal|
============================================
| machine-name  | machine-name  | Server   |
| Instance      | Instance      | Instance |
| Schema (User) | Database      | Name     |
| User (Schema) | User          | User     |
| Password      | Password      | Password |
--------------------------------------------
```

Are there any additions anyone else can see?